# NaN sInfo _TOTAL_ dataTable jquery/JSON

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-datatables

Estou com um problema em retorno do JSON na variável *TOTAL* que retorna NaN é estranho pq antes o problema era na variável *END* eu removi e adicionei *END* novamente e voltou ao normal mas, começou o NaN na váriavel *TOTAL*. Alguém pode em ajudar?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   oTable = $("#grid").dataTable({
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bServerSide": true,         
      "bPaginate": true,
      "iDisplayLength": 25,
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers", 
      "sAjaxSource": urlAjaxSource,
      "oLanguage": {
          "sSearch": "Procurar:",
      "sLengthMenu": "Exibir _MENU_ itens por página",
      "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado.",
      "sInfo": "Exibindo _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ itens"//onde acontece o erro _TOTAL_
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu Json precisa retornar esta estrutura abaixo para que o dataTables assuma os valores corretos de totais:

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [
    { [...]
```

Se ainda assim não resolver poste um pedaço do seu json para podermos avaliar melhor.

Comment: Verifique se as váriaveis de retorno estão sendo preenchidas e ou como estão sendo preenchidas:
{"iTotalRecords":
"iTotalDisplayRecords" }